# How can we access Google Work Space Add on in delegated gmail accounts

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-workspace-add-ons

I have delegated a gmail account (Ac-1) to another gmail account(Ac-2). I have a Google Workspace Add-on created in Ac-1. My question is: **how can we access that workspace Add-on while accessing the delegated account window from Ac-2**.
I tried to search about it online but could not find any info. Have started wondering if it is at all possible?
Any pointers in this direction will be a great help.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stack please edit your question include your code.  Spicily what you are using for authorization.  Describe the issues you are having.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.